# Shutil - Move and Rename

Tags: python

In my python script I am moving a bunch of files from different sub directories to one location the trouble with this is that there are multiple files the same.

The code I am currently running is:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.log'):            
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), FILE_LOCATION_PATH)
```

The trouble with this is it will throw the error eventually of:

```
  File "downloader.py", line 78, in <module>
    shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), FILE_LOCATION_PATH)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 548, in move
    raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
shutil.Error: Destination path '/home/a.log' already exists
```

I can negate this by changing my move line to copy such as the below

```
shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), FILE_LOCATION_PATH)
```

This will however replace any files with this name with the latest copy. I am trying to figure out a way I can rename any files with the same name to follow a naming convention like this

a.log

a_1.log

a_2.log

Any suggestions on how best to approach this or sample code. I am new to Python and trying to complete my first practical script.

Comment: you just have to use try block at first and in case of name collision do renaming like adding number at the end of file name or whatever is convenient to you

Comment: @Drako do you have any example code or links you could share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with filename like `filename.log, filename.log_1 ...` then code is just 4 lines more to your original code:

```
import shutil
import os

FILE_LOCATION_PATH='/destination/directory'
dir_path='/source/directory'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.log'):
            count = 1
            destination_file = os.path.join(FILE_LOCATION_PATH, file)
            while os.path.exists(destination_file):
                destination_file = os.path.join(FILE_LOCATION_PATH, f"{file}_{count}")
                count += 1
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), destination_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you need

```py
import re
import os
import shutil

FILE_LOCATION_PATH = 'dst'


def increment_file_name(f_name):
    """
    a.txt -> a_1.txt
    a_1.txt -> a_2.txt
    """

    def split_f_name(f_name):
        m = re.match(r"^(.+?)(_(\d+))?(\.(.+))??$", f_name)
        return m.group(1), int(m.group(3) or 0), m.group(5)

    def join_f_name(name, suffix, ext):
        if not ext:
            return "{}_{}".format(name, suffix)
        return "{}_{}.{}".format(name, suffix, ext)

    dirname = os.path.dirname(f_name)
    name, suffix, ext = split_f_name(os.path.basename(f_name))
    if dirname:
        return os.path.join(dirname, join_f_name(name, suffix + 1, ext))
    else:
        return join_f_name(name, suffix + 1, ext)


def safe_move(path):
    dir, f_name = os.path.split(path)
    while os.path.exists(os.path.join(FILE_LOCATION_PATH, f_name)):
        f_name = increment_file_name(f_name)
    shutil.move(path, os.path.join(FILE_LOCATION_PATH, f_name))


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('src'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.log'):
            safe_move(os.path.join(root, file))
```